# OpenGL: Textures are not aligned correctly

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, texture-mapping

I have a problem with OpenGL (in LWJGL) and Texture Mapping. I'm loading an ARGB image using

```
public static ByteBuffer toByteArray(BufferedImage image) {
    int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
    image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * 4);
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF)); // Red component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF)); // Green component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 0) & 0xFF)); // Blue component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF)); // Alpha component.
        }
    }
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}
```

I'm uploading the textures using

```
int[] textureIds = new int[textures.size()];
GL11.glGenTextures(textureIds);
int i = 0;
for (Texture texture : textures.values()) {
    int textureId = textureIds[i++];
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

    BufferedImage data = texture.load();
    ByteBuffer bytes = Texture.toByteArray(data);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, data.getWidth(), data.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA,
        GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
    // GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    texture.setTextureId(textureId);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Unfortunately I'm ending up with something like this:

[image: this]

But actually it should look like this (in blender):

[image: this]

The Texture can be found: [Here is the texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygQjf.jpg)

So everything is crooked and somewhat following diagonals. The model is made with blender and therefore has proper texture coordinates. I also managed it to load the model plus texture in another engine. But not in mine. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I triangulated them. The image is also drawn using GL_TRIANGLES. I avoid usage of quads.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The model is already normalized to triangles in blender using their algorithms. I read the already defined triangles from a wavefront OBJ. That seems to be working. But of course I'll check it

Comment: Could you explain what we are seeing in the image? It is pretty hard to tell without knowing the scene. Could you show how the scene looks like in Blender and the texture?

Comment: Hey Nico. Its basically a room with a table. As you expected I added an image of the scene in blender and a link to the baked texture (without the table and matrix - these are separate objects). So the 4 walls, the ceiling and the floor are the mapped to the texture.

Comment: Okay thanks. I got it. Mistake was on loading wavefront obj. Did a off by one error on retrieving correkt vertex texture coordinates from face entry. That was a hint in a comment here that seems to be deleted.